# Increasing SQLite SELECT performance

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, sqlite

I have a program that does some math in an SQL query. There are hundreds of thousands rows (some device measurements) in an SQLite table, and using this query, the application breaks these measurements into groups of, for example, 10000 records, and calculates the average for each group. Then it returns the average value for each of these groups.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT strftime('%s',Min(Stamp)) AS DateTimeStamp, 
AVG(P) AS MeasuredValue, 
((100 * (strftime('%s', [Stamp]) - 1334580095)) / 
    (1336504574 - 1334580095)) AS SubIntervalNumber 
FROM LogValues 
WHERE ((DeviceID=1) AND (Stamp >=  datetime(1334580095, 'unixepoch')) AND 
    (Stamp <= datetime(1336504574, 'unixepoch'))) 
GROUP BY ((100 * (strftime('%s', [Stamp]) - 1334580095)) / 
    (1336504574 - 1334580095)) ORDER BY MIN(Stamp)
```

The numbers in this request are substituted by my application with some values. 
I don't know if i can optimize this request more (if anyone could help me to do so, i'd really appreciate)..

This SQL query can be executed using an SQLite command line shell (sqlite3.exe). On my Intel Core i5 machine it takes 4 seconds to complete (there are 100000 records in the database that are being processed).

Now, if i write a C program, using sqlite.h C interface, I am waiting for 14 seconds for exactly the same query to complete. This C program "waits" during these 14 seconds on the first sqlite3_step() function call (any following sqlite3_step() calls are executed immediately).

From the [Sqlite download page](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) I have downloaded SQLite command line shell's source code and build it using Visual Studio 2008. I ran it and executed the query. Again 14 seconds.

So why does a prebuilt, downloaded from the sqlite website, command line tool takes only 4 seconds, while the same tool, built by me, takes 4 times longer time to execute?

I am running Windows 64 bit. The prebuilt tool is an x86 process. It also does not seem to be multicore optimized - in a Task Manager, during query execution, I can see only one core busy, for both built-by-mine and prebuilt SQLite shells.

Any way I could make my C program execute this query as fast as the prebuilt command line tool does it?

Thanks!